# Фильтрация арифметического выражения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Введенное пользователем арифметическое выражение должно содержать арабские или римские числа от 1 до 10 || от I до X и один оператор [+-/*] в формате 1 + 2 или I + II, т.е. операнд --> пробел --> оператор --> пробел --> операнд.

Если вводим числа отвечающие условиям - то выходим из цикла, если нет - предлагаем ввести заново.

Только начал знакомиться с регулярками, написал, но отрабатывает она некорректно:

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String expression;
    Matcher matcher;

    do {
        expression = s.nextLine();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z*|1-10?]\\s[-+*/]\\s[A-Z*|1-10?]");
        matcher = pattern.matcher(expression);
    } while (!matcher.find());

    // код при выходе из цикла
```

Comment: 1. римские числа могут содержать только 7 букв, а не от A до Z.  2. Выражение [1-10?] **не означает** от 1 до 10.

Comment: @Эникейщик, спасибо за комментарий. Могу предположить, что фильтрация римских чисел от I до X может осуществляться такой регуляркой: 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[IVX{1,4}]\\s[-+*/]\\s[IVX{1,4}]");
Но тогда в эту же выборку попадают числа больше X, такие как: XI, XII, XVI и т.д. Как ограничить эту выборку?
И по арабским числам совсем непонятно. Допускаю, что можно использовать \\d, но тогда как задать диапазон допустимых на ввод чисел (1 - 10)?

Comment: Числа от 1 до 10 - это ИЛИ один знак от 1 до 9 ИЛИ 10 (если нельзя использовать 01, 02 и т.д.) С римскими от I до X примерно так же, по аналогии, но чуток сложнее.

Comment: `(?:\b(?:I{1,3}[VX]?|[VX]|VI{1,3})\b\s?[-+*/]\s?\b(?:I{1,3}[VX]?|[VX]|VI{1,3})\b|\b(?:[0-9]|10)\b\s?[-+*]\s?\b(?:[0-9]|10)\b)` ну вот что-то такое нарисовывается. Пример: https://regex101.com/r/HVz4Rk/1

Comment: @ipatev_nn, спасибо, но что-то не работает) - пропускает выражения 2 + 12 и V / XVII.

Тоже пытаюсь своять регулярку, но пока безрезультатно

Comment: @Astor очень странно что пропускает, добавьте код в вопрос, попробую понять в чем дело

Comment: @Astor https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RlWR.png - у меня проблема с вашим кодом и моим regex не повторяется

Comment: ^(?=[MDCLXVI])M*(C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(I[XV]|V?I{0,3})$"

Comment: @ipatev_nn, протестил еще раз, вроде все работает корректно, кроме операций деления: 2 / 2, 5 / 2 и т.д.  Но проблему нашел в вашей регулярке - во втором блоке операторов отсутствовал символ деления. Добавил и все работает корректно.

Единственный момент -  регулярка не пропускает выражения типа VI / 2, т.е. те, где участвуют обе системы арабская и римская.

Сделайте свой коммент ответом, чтобы я мог чекнуть его, как верный.
Было бы здорово, если бы вы кратко прокомментировали вашу регулярку по шагам.
А еще лучше, если посоветуете книгу или ресурс, по которому можно освоить регэкспы.

Comment: Регулярные выражения Сборник рецептов  Ян Гойвертс Стивен Левитан

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регулярное выражение:

```regex
(?:\b(?:I{1,3}[VX]?|[VX]|VI{1,3})\b\s?[-+*/]\s?\b(?:I{1,3}[VX]?|[VX]|VI{1,3})\b|\b(?:[0-9]|10)\b\s?[-+*/]\s?\b(?:[0-9]|10)\b)
```

Основная часть в данном случае состоит из не захватываемой группы с логическим или `(?:...|...)` и включает в себя либо арабские цифры, либо римские.
Далее каждый блок отдельно:

---

```
\b(?:I{1,3}[VX]?|[VX]|VI{1,3})\b\s?[-+*/]\s?\b(?:I{1,3}[VX]?|[VX]|VI{1,3})\b
```

`\b` - границы слова, что бы исключить совпадения с частью цифры
`I{1,3}[VX]?` - от одно до 3х символов `I` после которых необязательно идут символы `V` или `X`
`|[VX]` - или одиночный символ `V` или `X`
`|VI{1,3}` - или одиночный символ V после которого идет от одного до трех символов `I`
`\b\s?` - граница слова и необязательный пробельный символ, т.е. `X+` и `X +` будут подходить
`[-+*/]` - один из математических символов
Далее, по аналогии с выше описанным - необязательный любой пробельный символ, границы слова, и выбор римской цифры от I до X.

---

```
\b(?:[0-9]|10)\b\s?[-+*/]\s?\b(?:[0-9]|10)\b
```

`\b` - граница слова
`(?:[0-9]|10)` - диапазон цифр от 0 до 9 или 10
`\b\s?` - граница слова и необязательный пробельный символ
`[-+*/]` - один из математических операторов
и т.д

---

Если нужно оставить возможность комбинировать арабские и римские цифры, то можно внести следующие изменения:

```
\b(?:I{1,3}[VX]?|[VX]|VI{1,3}|[0-9]|10)\b\s?[-+*/]\s?\b(?:I{1,3}[VX]?|[VX]|VI{1,3}|[0-9]|10)\b
```

через логическое или в группы добавлен диапазон цифр от 0 до 9 или 10, тогда выражение `I + 10` или `2 + IIV` - станут подходить под захват данным регулярным выражением.

---

По поводу литературы, сообществом уже добавлены несколько книг в метку, а так же справочный материал
[[Регулярные выражения]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/info)